# jQuery-File-Upload fails with somewhat large files

Tags: jquery-file-upload, apache2.4, php-7.2

Trying to use this project: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

Our application server is a FreeBSD 11.2 with Apache 2.4.39 and PHP 7.2.17. I've downloaded their demo and receive the error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in the browser console when trying to upload anything large enough to exceed 22 seconds exactly. It does appear to be server related as I've downloaded the same demo to another CentOS7 server where same file upload succeeds.

Although I have checked all my PHP variables for max upload size and memory limit, etc., would this demo be subject to PHP variables? I found the `RequestReadTimeout` Apache setting in the server that fails, not present in the working server, so I thought it could be the culprit, but I changed this setting from...

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
```

To this...

```
RequestReadTimeout header=60-120,MinRate=500 body=120,MinRate=500
```

...and restarted Apache, but the same result. The developers on this server believe this issue only started after recent updates to the server were done that included Apache 2.4.33 upgraded to Apache 2.4.39. The PHP version did not change, however, there were many other packages updated as well as security patches to the FreeBSD OS. Can someone suggest what could fix this issue?

--UPDATE--

Okay, this is easily duplicated. I spun up a VM with a fresh install of FreeBSD 11.2, installed Apache 2.4.39 and the demo of this project. I adjusted these settings in the demo app to allow a large mp4 video to be uploaded...

```
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|mp4)$/i,
maxFileSize: 999000000,
```

...and receive the same `Unknown error` at exactly 22 seconds into the download progress of an mp4 file of ~493MB. There must be a setting in Apache that needs to allow more time or other limit. And perhaps a change to the FreeBSD Apache 2.4 port somewhere between 2.4.33 and 2.4.39. My developers say this all started after that update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `RequestReadTimeout` setting in Apache was the culprit. I had to completely disable, now it works.

Comment: same here, seems that 2.4.39 introduced the issue. We have a Linux Ami that experienced large file upload issues after upgrade to 2.4.39, but it's still not clear to me why stopped working. Looking at the documentation 2.4.39 just introduced the handshake timeout, but is defaulted to 0, the rest is the same..

Answer (score 0):

same issue here - to fix, on a Centos 7 system, comment out this line:
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
from the 00-base.conf file, then restart httpd